# move constructor: how to handle container attribute?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

How to properly initialize container attribute avoiding reconstructing contained objects?

```
class BAR
{
...
};

class FOO
{
  public:
  FOO(FOO &&f)
  {
    // ????
  }

  std::vector<BAR> b;
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you have a good reason for doing otherwise, just [**follow the Rule of Zero**](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/) and avoid defining a move constructor explicitly: the compiler will generate one for you implicitly, and that move constructor will perform a member-wise move of the class data members.

If you really have to define a move constructor explicitly (e.g. because you are using MSVC, and for some obscure reason MSVC will *never* generate a move constructor for you implicitly), do it this way:

```
Foo(Foo&& f) : b(std::move(f.b)) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

See Andy's answer, but if you need to:

```
class FOO
{
public:
  FOO(FOO &&f) : b(std::move(f.b))
  {

  }

  std::vector<BAR> b;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be

```
FOO(FOO &&f): b(std::move(f.b))
{
}
```

But it's not necessary, as others have pointed out, it's the implicit move constructor will generate for you.